# Is it possible to exchange the render functions of VueJS-Components during runtime?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've played around with `vue-i18n` and `Vue.compile()` and found a very static solution to my problem. While searching for a solution I've tried to dynamically set the render functions during runtime. Unfortunately without any success.

Out of curiosity: Is it possible to exchange the render functions of Components during runtime?

I try to do something like this:

```
{
    props: {
        toCompile: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        callbackFn: {
            type: Function,
            default: () => {}
        }
    },
    created (){
        let res = Vue.compile(this.toCompile);
        this.render = res.render;
        this.staticRenderFns = res.staticRenderFns;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Can you provide details?

Comment: Okay I've added one of my attempts.

Comment: Will `toCompile` change over the lifetime of the Vue?

Comment: In my case: no. Which is why i found a static solution, only declaring my component where I need it.But for the big picture: yes it might.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach is working for me:

```
{
   ...
    methods: {
        render: function () {
            var createElement = this.$createElement;
            return (this._self._c || createElement)("div", {
                staticClass: "element"
            });
        }
    },
    beforeCreate: function() {
        this.$vnode.componentOptions.Ctor.options.render = this.$vnode.componentOptions.Ctor.options.methods.render.bind(this);
    }
}
```

If your want slots as well, use the following render method:

```
        render: function () {
            var that = this,
                createElement = (this._self._c || this.$createElement),
                children = Object.keys(that.$slots).map(function(slot) {
                    return createElement('template', { slot }, that.$slots[slot]);
                });
            return createElement('div', [
                createElement('component-element, {
                    attrs: that.$attrs,
                    on: that.$listeners,
                    scopedSlots: that.$scopedSlots,
                }, children)
            ]);
        }
```